# Is there a function that will return a symbol name, such as `EIO`, for an `errno` value?

Tags: posix, errno

On Linux and OS X, `strerror` returns a human-readable name. For example, here's what it returned on Linux just now for error number 5.

```
Input/output error
```

That's fine, but the man pages use a symbolic name, such as `EIO`, and don't list the corresponding number. Is there a function anywhere that I can use to get the symbolic name?

Comment: (Please assume I don't want to write my own function to do this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt that pure POSIX provides facilities to accomplish that in a portable fashion. In most cases I personally just open the `/usr/include/errno.h` file in editor and browse it from there. (On Linux that eventually leads to `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` and `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h` files where the codes are actually specified.)

Also, for systems with GCC (or clang), I could come up with the scriptlet like this:

```
gcc -dM -E - < /usr/include/errno.h  |
    grep 'define E\w\+ [0-9]\+$'  |
    sort -k3 -n
```

The GNU preprocessor has an option (`-dM`) to print all defines it encounters to the output. That can be used to help parse the `/usr/include/errno.h` file to extract the error codes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, it's looking as if this is what I'll have to do. (I was hoping not to have to do this, as I don't really want to take on the burden of keeping the mapping up to date when/if additional system-specific errors are introduced.)

Comment: Yes, it is omission. The error codes are added/removed fairly rarely - most often inadvertently. Most commonly occurring errors are the "usual suspects" like "access denied" or "no space left on device" and they have stable numeric codes. If you would keep mapping in your program, you wouldn't need to update it very often. Just don't forget also to log the numeric error code.